# Unhandled Promise rejection: loginUrl must use Http. Also check property requireHttps

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0

I am trying to redirect app to my login page via auth-2 service.

Below is my code.

```
private _router: Router, private _http: Http, private oauthService: OAuthService) {
    this.oauthService.loginUrl = 'http://172.30.10.207:8080/uaa/oauth/authorize';
    this.oauthService.redirectUri = 'http://localhost:4200/';
    this.oauthService.clientId = 'web_app';
    this.oauthService.scope = 'openid';
    this.oauthService.setStorage(sessionStorage);
    this.oauthService.oidc = false;
    this.oauthService.tryLogin({});
}
```

if the user is logged in then it will redirect to http://localhost:4200/' else it will redirect to 'http://172.30.10.207:8080/uaa/oauth/authorize'.

But i am getting below error in console.

```
AppComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR Error: loginUrl must use Http. Also check property requireHttps.
at OAuthService.webpackJsonp.../../../../angular-oauth2-oidc/angular-oauth2-oidc.umd.js.OAuthService.initImplicitFlowInternal (angular-oauth2-oidc.umd.js:1403)
at OAuthService.webpackJsonp.../../../../angular-oauth2-oidc/angular-oauth2-oidc.umd.js.OAuthService.initImplicitFlow (angular-oauth2-oidc.umd.js:1440)
at AppService.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/app.service.ts.AppService.obtainAccessToken (app.service.ts:28)
at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:29)
at createClass (core.es5.js:10912)
at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10751)
at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12192)
at createRootView (core.es5.js:12082)
at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13467)
at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12771)
```

Can anybody help me with this.

Comment: What does your `AuthConfig` look like?

Comment: Did you solve this errror ?